# LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER in API 9 and 10 in Android

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying out LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER with API 9 and 10 (2.3 and below 3.0). It cannot get the latitude/longitude values if Internet (Wireless or data) is Off? I am not sure why?

It just works fine on android 4.0 and more.

I am using the following:

```
locationListenerForNetwork  = new MyLocationListenerForNetwork();
location.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerForNetwork );


private class MyLocationListenerForNetwork implements LocationListener 
 {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
    {
                 //I do what I required in this place..
            }
   }
}
```

Has anybody had the same issue?

Comment: Could you show more code? Did you try to use another constructor on `location.requestLocationUpdates()`?

Comment: I don't have anything other than the above to call the location listner. As I said before it works just fine on Android 4.0  and above version why not on Android 2.3 versions...

Answer (score 0):

Try making the call to requestLocationUpdates() with different parameters.

Make your class implementing LocationListener,
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks and
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener and add the methods from those interfaces (`onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)`, `onConnected()` and `onDisconnected()`).

Then, create a LocationRequest and a LocationClient:

```
 // Create a new global location parameters object
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    /*
     * Set the update interval
     */
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
     * handle callbacks.
     */
    LocationClient mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
```

Finally, make the call to get update requests:

```
mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain why do we require  requestLocationUpdates() with different parameters? My issue I am not able to get the LatandLong in when I am using Network provider (This is only when the wireless network / data (Internet) is disabled)

Comment: @TheDevMan If you try, maybe you solve your issue. 
You can also use getLastKnownLocation() to get your last LatLng received value.